# cakephp3: Error: Class 'Time' not found

Tags: cakephp

in Controller/AppController.php I have

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;
Time::$defaultLocale = 'de-DE';
```

But when I try to use this in a view

```
$today = Time::now();
```

or

```
$today = $this->Time->now();
```

I get the error:

> Error: Class 'Time' not found.

or

> Method Cake\View\Helper\TimeHelper::now does not exist

What works fine is something like this in my view:

```
$this->Time->format($item->invoicedate, 'd.MM.Y')
```

I need to compare dates for checking if the invoice it due or not.
How can I get todays date in order to compare with the the date I have stored in $item->invoicedate?

Comment: you have to put use `Cake\I18n\Time;` in your .ctp file too or use the full syntax `\Cake\I18n\Time::now()`

Comment: Thanks! This worked out for me! But I find it really strange that putting this in AppController is not valid for all files even views?

Comment: If this surprises you I highly recommend you to step away from developing blindly without knowing what you do and start reading the namespace section of the php language manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php There are even more "strange" things that can be done with namespaces.